# How can I install jython in a r-pi?

Tags: raspbian

Someone knows **How can I install jython or Jpython in a raspberry pi on raspbian?** because I search but there is nothing clear.

Comment: why do you need `jython`, when you can use full-fledged `python`?

Comment: @lenik: because with `jython` you are able to use `Java` Libraries inside your "Python" programm because it is executed in the `JRE`.

Answer (score 1):

according to this command:

```
$ apt-cache search jython
jython - Python seamlessly integrated with Java
jython-doc - Jython documentation including API docs
```

you may install `jython` on Raspberry Pi by running:

```
$ sudo apt-get install jython
```

however `jython` on raspberry is very slow, here's a quote from [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reading-hackspace/S-BykPs6o0o):

```
$ time python hello.py
Hello, World
platform is linux2

real    0m0.211s
user    0m0.160s
sys    0m0.040s
$ time jython hello.py
Hello, World
platform is java1.7.0_40

real    0m35.639s
user    0m33.830s
sys    0m1.420s
```

Yes, that's right. 35 seconds to say "Hello, World".

Comment: Most of that time is the JVM starting up. For any application with a bit more meat than hello world, the timings would be more realistic.